# Django - How to allow access to read one model object from another django site hosted on another server

Tags: django, django-models

Like I said in the title, I need to know how can I allow access to the objects from one model of a Django app from another Django app.

For example, I have a Django App on one VPS, and the other on another VPS. In the first one, I publish daily news about science. I like to put a div in the other Django app landing page that shows the news that I publish in the first app.

I know that I didn't put any code, but this is because I don't know how to start. I need the first push to help me figure how to make this and then I'm pretty sure that I can come back to make specific questions.

Comment: You could [make your information available with an API](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/), but for your use case it may also make sense to [provide an RSS feed](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/syndication/), which may be generally useful to other users, and then consume it from the other site.

Comment: thanks i think RSS Feed goes perfect for what i need. Going to try that. Thanks!